# What is the jackson compatability for Jooq 3.14.6?

Tags: jackson, jooq, jooq-codegen

I am trying to upgrade jackson to 2.13.4 from 2.12.6 due to [CVE-2022-42004](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2022-42004). I am using jooq 3.14.6.

With jackson 2.13.4 I am getting the below exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.exc.StreamWriteException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods (Class.java:3166)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethodsRecursive (Class.java:3307)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0 (Class.java:3293)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod (Class.java:2106)
    at org.jooq.tools.Convert.<clinit> (Convert.java:198)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultConverterProvider$1.from (DefaultConverterProvider.java:126)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractRecord.get (AbstractRecord.java:285)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractRecord.get (AbstractRecord.java:300)
    at org.jooq.meta.h2.H2Database.getTables0 (H2Database.java:468)
    at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase$7.run (AbstractDatabase.java:1673)
    at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase.onError (AbstractDatabase.java:3094)
    at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase.getTables (AbstractDatabase.java:1670)
    at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase.getEmbeddables0 (AbstractDatabase.java:1957)
    at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase.access$1100 (AbstractDatabase.java:124)
    at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase$9.run (AbstractDatabase.java:1915)
    at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase.onError (AbstractDatabase.java:3094)
    at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase.getEmbeddables (AbstractDatabase.java:1912)
    at org.jooq.meta.AbstractDatabase.getEmbeddables (AbstractDatabase.java:1935)
    at org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator.generateSchemaIfEmpty (JavaGenerator.java:493)
    at org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator.generateCatalogIfEmpty (JavaGenerator.java:481)
    at org.jooq.codegen.JavaGenerator.generate (JavaGenerator.java:435)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.run0 (GenerationTool.java:879)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.run (GenerationTool.java:233)
    at org.jooq.codegen.GenerationTool.generate (GenerationTool.java:228)
    at com.spotnana.analytics.snowflake.JooqBindingsGenerator.generateBindings (JooqBindingsGenerator.java:60)
    at com.spotnana.analytics.snowflake.JooqBindingsGenerator.main (JooqBindingsGenerator.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:254)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:829)
```

Is there any compatibility matrix for Jooq and jackson? What is the minimum Jooq version which works with jackson 2.13.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the jooq-parent project to see which version are used:

https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.jooq/jooq-parent/3.17.4/pom

```
<jackson.version>2.13.3</jackson.version>
```

jOOQ 3.17.5 supports Jackson 2.13.4

Comment: I did check jooq-parent pom but I did not find any version of jackson mentioned there for jooq 3.14.6 https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.jooq/jooq-parent/3.14.6/pom

Comment: Oh you are using a very old version didn't noticed that. You can run mvn dependency:tree and check where the jackson dependency comes from